# Python Read base 64 string from xml file to byte array similar to QT

Tags: python, xml, qt, base64

I am reading a base64 string from xml file. The base64 string written to xml file is generated from QTc++ program. I have The Qtc++ program which parses the xml file and able to generate the data from base64 string.I want to do the same with python i am unable to figure how to read the base64 as byte array similar to QTc++. 
My Qt c++ code which parses the xml and decode the data file looks like below. For simplicity i am just including a part of encoded base64 string.

```
          datastring='AAAAAAAAAAA/YGJN0vGp/D9wYk3S8an8P3iTdLxqfvo/'            

          QByteArray xByteArray =QByteArray::fromBase64('datastring')
          QDataStream xInStream(xByteArray);
            while (!xInStream.atEnd())
            {
              double d;
              xInStream >> d;
              qDebug()<<d;
              pPlotCurve->addXAxisValue(d);
            }
```

I am able to decode the data using QTc++ the output looks like [0.0, 0.002 0.004,......]

I am trying to decode the same base64 string in python, i am getting scrambled data. My Python Code is

```
            import base64
            # I parse the xml file and retrieve the data below
            datastring = 'AAAAAAAAAAA/YGJN0vGp/D9wYk3S8an8P3iTdLxqfvo/'
            out = base64.b64decode(datastring)
            print out
```

When i decode this the above code i am getting scrambled data, how can i perform the same operation like the above QTc++ program and get the same output. I tried lot of methods but nothing worked.

Comment: sorry it should be datastring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64.b64decode` will take your base64 string and return bytes.  Those bytes are just a pile of bits with no meaning.  You need to tell Python how to turn those bits into meaningful data.

Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to tell Python how to interpret your binary data:

```
import base64
import struct
data_base64 = 'AAAAAAAAAAA/YGJN0vGp/D9wYk3S8an8P3iTdLxqfvo/'
data_bytes = base64.b64decode(data_base64)
# '>ddddx' big endian, 4 8-byte floating point plus 1 extra byte
struct.unpack('>ddddx', data_bytes) 
# gives (0.0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006)
```

To unpack an arbitrary number of doubles do:

```
[struct.unpack_from('>d', data_bytes, offset)[0] for offset in range(0, len(data_bytes), 8)]
# gives [0.0, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006]
```

Note that your example data is 33 bytes long.  If you use this second method make sure the length of your bytes is a multiple of 8, otherwise you will get `struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 8 bytes`.

Comment: Ok can you tell me what is that '>ddddx' means when unpacking

Comment: @arun:  The comment explains it.  Also the linked documentation gives more details.

Comment: Now if i decode my whole base64 string .I am getting this                     ERROR:  unpack requires a string argument of length 33

Comment: Thank you very very much it worked, I will now look into this struct package and learn more